# Four part iOS bundle identifiers

Tags: ios, cfbundleidentifier

Most examples of bundle identifiers have three parts.  Are four part bundle identifiers valid in iOS?  How about n-part?  (n > 3)

```
com.companyname.divisionname.appname
[1st name].[2nd name]...[n-1th name].[nth name]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit I know of. I personally used bundleIDs with up to 6 parts, they all passed verification and now live happily in the App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Asking another question, can you have a server named: `some.thing.really.long.example.com`?

It's essentially just a name.  All commercial companies/products should start with `com` and so on.  By having this convention, it (technically, though legality is another issue) allows two products with the same name but by different companies.

**At the end of the day** :  It's just a string following an established convention.